# Nodejs RESTful API res is returning a previous result (always one step behind)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Requesting a list from Mongodb database, I get my last results instead of the updated ones.

I've tried:

- calling from different clients (web browser, Postman and vscode's Rest-client)
- adding async/await
- res.send instead of res.json
- changing mongoose versions

Example:

```
exports.get_users_list = (req, res) => {
  User.find().then((users) => {
    console.log(users);
    res.status(200).json(users)
  }).catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
};
```

or

```
exports.get_users_list = async (req, res) => {
  result = await User.find();
  await console.log(result);
  res.json(result);
};
```

Expected that console.log(result) and res.json(result) will be similar

Actual result is that in res.json (result) the data is always one step behind (as if it reads from cache or some previous snapshot).

Any advice would be appreciated (:

Happy coding!

Comment: You don't need to do `await console.log(result)` have you tried just logging it without the `await`?

Comment: Actual result is that in res.json (result) the data is always one step behind. you mean res.json(result) is executed after console.log(result)

Comment: @Intellidroid i know , ignore it - was just out of frustration ( : doesnt effect anything

Comment: @Yilmaz what i mean is if i had 2 items in results and i deleted one, next call gives 1 result in console but 2 in res.json, next call i will get 1

Answer (score 0):

Just one question is your console.log showing the correct result.
If so can you try the below code

```
exports.get_users_list = (req, res) => {
  User.find().then((users) => {
    console.log(users);
    res.status(200).send(users)
  }).catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
};
```

Comment: i tried the parse method and got: SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 4 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: You dont have to JSON.parse your result (forgot about that....). I have edited the code above. It should work in your case

Comment: Hi @Walter , thanks for your help, but that gives the same results.. i always need to send the request a second time to get the right response

Answer (score 0):

Try adding {new:true} keyword, it will work.
example: 
await Complaint.findByIdAndUpdate(complaintid, complaintData,{new:true});

Comment: i added the {new:true} to find() the result is the same original problem only this time it gives an empty array instead ) :

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be my faulty express setup,
writing from scratch express using my original methods solves it.
(was much quicker then debugging for me)
thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

yes you just add {new:true} like this,  it's works very well

```js
      const updatedCart = await Cart.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, cart, {
        new: true,
      });
```